# Extracting values within spatial polygons using a tif. file

Tags: r

I am working with 15 spatial polygons and want to extract values from a tif. file (i.e using a vector). This tif. file has already been reclassified by me to represent slope data (per pixel).

PROBLEM: I have managed to create a "list" from my 15 polygons and also retrieve the codes that I associated with their category of slope incline, but throughout this process i have lost all recognition of which polygon is which? Does anyone know why this is?

```
#Matrix to categorise my 5 slope categories within each polygon
m <- matrix (c(0, 5, 1,
            5, 10, 2,
            10, 15, 3,
            15, 20, 4,
            20, Inf, 5), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)

r2 <- reclassify(Slope, m)
r2
plot(r2)

#Loading of polygons (NewHRs02)
All02HRs<-shapefile("L:\\GPSdatabackup\\KERNELS\\NewHRs02")
plot(All02HRs)
All02HRs

#Attempt to extract slope using polygons but i loose recognition of each polygon? THEREFORE WRONG!
Exp02poly <- extract(r2, All02HRs)
summary(Exp02poly)
str(Exp02poly)
class(Exp02poly)
unlist(lapply(Exp02poly, function(x) if (!is.null(x)) freq(x, na.rm=TRUE) else NA ))

##I suspect the final line needs some adjusting but i cannot think what command would be required here.
```

Hope someone can help please

Comment: Sorry something has gone wrong with this text formatting

Comment: Thank you for editing the incorrect formatting Sven